# Can Rust call abstract functions?

Tags: rust, traits

I found some complicated code in the [websocket](http://cyderize.github.io/rust-websocket/doc/websocket/index.html) library which seems to call an abstract function in the [`Receiver`](http://cyderize.github.io/rust-websocket/doc/websocket/ws/receiver/trait.Receiver.html#method.recv_message) trait.

```
fn recv_message<'m, D, M, I>(&mut self) -> WebSocketResult<M>
    where M: Message<'m, D, DataFrameIterator = I>,
          I: Iterator<Item = D>,
          D: DataFrame
{
    let dataframes = try!(self.recv_message_dataframes());
    Message::from_dataframes(dataframes) // Isn't this an abstract function?
}
```

The code for `ws::Message` trait:

```
pub trait Message<'a, F>: Sized
    where F: DataFrame
{
    type DataFrameIterator: Iterator<Item = F>;
    fn from_dataframes<D>(frames: Vec<D>) -> WebSocketResult<Self> where D: DataFrame;
    fn dataframes(&'a self) -> Self::DataFrameIterator;
}
```

It looks like it shouldn't work because Rust wouldn't know which function to call.  How does it work?

Answer (score 3):

The key is the signature of the method:

```
fn from_dataframes<D>(frames: Vec<D>) -> WebSocketResult<Self>
```

When the compiler goes to unify the types, it can use the return type of `recv_message` (*i.e.* `WebSocketResult<M>`) to infer that the result of `from_dataframes` must be the same type, which means the `Self` type in question is `M`, which means that what you *really* meant was:

```
<M as Message>::from_dataframes(dataframes)
```

If there was no connection between the implementing type and the method signature, then it wouldn't work, because the compiler would have nothing to base its reasoning on.

Comment: Rust's type system is so smart ! Thanks for answering !

Comment: @AtsukiTakahashi: Pedantically, this is not the type system but the compiler being smart here. And yes, rustc is all kinds of smart!